# Нажатие правой кнопкой мыши

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, borland

Можно ли при нажатии правой кнопки мыши в компоненте `TWebBrowser` оставить только 2 элемента: Копировать и Обновить?
Если нельзя, то как её вообще убрать? Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы перехватить правый клик в TWebBrowser нужен хук на события мыши.

Установка хука в OnCreate формы:

```
HMouseHook := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE, @MouseProc, HInstance, GetCurrentThreadID);
```

Снятие хука в OnDestroy:

```
UnhookWindowsHookEx(HMouseHook);
```

Обработчик:

```
function MouseProc(nCode: Integer; WP: wParam; LP: lParam): Integer; stdcall;
var
  MHS: TMouseHookStruct;
  WC: TWinControl;
begin
  Result := CallNextHookEx(HMouseHook, nCode, WP, LP);
  if nCode = HC_ACTION then
  begin
    MHS := PMOUSEHOOKSTRUCT(LP)^;
    if (WP = WM_RBUTTONDOWN) or (WP = WM_RBUTTONUP) then
    begin
      // Определяем контрол под курсором
      WC := FindVCLWindow(MHS.pt);
      // Если это TWebBrowser и у него есть PopupMenu, то вызываем PopupMenu
      if WC is TWebBrowser then
      begin
        Result := 1;
        if (TWebBrowser(WC).PopupMenu <> nil) and (WP = WM_RBUTTONUP) then
        begin
          if Pop then
            Exit;
          Pop := True;
          TWebBrowser(WC).PopupMenu.Popup(MHS.pt.x, MHS.pt.y);
          Pop := False;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```